# Is there a way to add only changed files to a docker image as a new layer - without resorting to docker commit?

Tags: docker

**TL;DR**

Running `COPY . /app` on top of an image with but slightly outdated source code creates a new layer as large as the whole source code, even when there is only a few bytes worth of changes.
Is there a way to add only changed files to this docker image as a new layer - without resorting to docker commit?

**Long version:**

When deploying our application to production, we need to add the source code to the image. A very simple Dockerfile is used for this:

```
FROM neam/dna-project-base-debian-php:0.6.0
COPY . /app
```

Since the source code is huge (1.2 GB), this makes for quite a hefty push upon each deploy:

```
$ docker build -f .stack.php.Dockerfile -t project/project-web-src-php:git-commit-17c279b .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.254 GB
Step 0 : FROM neam/dna-project-base-debian-php:0.6.0
 ---> 299c10c416fc
Step 1 : COPY . /app
 ---> 78a30802804a
Removing intermediate container 13b49c323bb6
Successfully built 78a30802804a

$ docker tag -f project/project-web-src-php:git-commit-17c279b tutum.co/project/project-web-src-php:git-commit-17c279b
$ docker login --email=tutum-project@project.com --username=project --password=******** https://tutum.co/v1
WARNING: login credentials saved in /home/dokku/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
$ docker push tutum.co/project/project-web-src-php:git-commit-17c279b
The push refers to a repository [tutum.co/project/project-web-src-php] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository tutum.co/project/project-web-src-php (1 tags)
Image a604b236bcde already pushed, skipping
Image 1565e86129b8 already pushed, skipping
...
Image 71156b357f2f already pushed, skipping
Image 299c10c416fc already pushed, skipping
78a30802804a: Pushing [=========>                     ] 234.2 MB/1.254 GB
```

Upon the next deploy, we only want to add the changed files to the image, but watch and behold when running `COPY . /app` on top of the previously added image actually requires us to push 1.2 GB worth of source code AGAIN, even when we only change a few bytes worth of source code:

New Dockerfile (`.stack.php.git-commit-17c279b.Dockerfile`):

```
FROM project/project-web-src-php:git-commit-17c279b
COPY . /app
```

After change a few files, adding some text and code, then building and pushing:

```
$ docker build -f .stack.php.git-commit-17c279b.Dockerfile -t project/project-web-src-php:git-commit-17c279b-with-a-few-changes .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.225 GB
Step 0 : FROM project/project-web-src-php:git-commit-17c279b
 ---> 4dc643a45de3
Step 1 : COPY . /app
 ---> ecc7adc194c4
Removing intermediate container cb3e87c6cb7a
Successfully built ecc7adc194c4
$ docker tag -f project/project-web-src-php:git-commit-17c279b-with-a-few-changes tutum.co/project/project-web-src-php:git-commit-17c279b-with-a-few-changes
$ docker push tutum.co/project/project-web-src-php:git-commit-17c279b-with-a-few-changes
The push refers to a repository [tutum.co/project/project-web-src-php] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository tutum.co/project/project-web-src-php (1 tags)
Image 1565e86129b8 already pushed, skipping
Image a604b236bcde already pushed, skipping
...
Image fe64bff23cf8 already pushed, skipping
Image 71156b357f2f already pushed, skipping
ecc7adc194c4: Pushing [==>                           ] 68.21 MB/1.225 GB
```

There is a workaround to achieve small layers as described on [Updating docker images with small changes using commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014503/updating-docker-images-with-small-changes-using-commits) which includes launching a rsync process within the image and then using docker commit to save the new contents as a new layer, however (as mentioned in that thread) this is unorthodox since the image is not built from a Dockerfile, and we prefer an orthodox solution that does not rely on docker commit.

Is there a way to add only changed files to this docker image as a new layer - without resorting to docker commit?

Docker version 1.8.3

Comment: If you pulled the source onto the image using `git` instead of using `COPY` or `ADD` I think you would get what you want (because you would then have an existing git repository on the image, and `git pull` would just bring in new/updated files).

Comment: @larsks Thanks, but it won't help when the build process is more elaborate than running git pull. It may start with git pull, but include handling of sensitive configuration directives, composer/npm/etc dependency installation and running of unit and acceptance tests before the source code is stamped as ok to land on the production-grade docker image. Running all of that could take longer than to push the source code in the first place so it would not be a favorable trade-off. Looking for solutions that help minimize the layer size to a few kb.

Comment: It's your best bet though, probably one of the few cases where I would abuse git as a artefact repository. Commit the build result to a seperate release branch/repo and your problem becomes fairly trivial to solve. Not sure if still correct but there used to be a hard limit on layers of 127 per image. You probably want to check if that still applies.

Comment: @Erik, that may be OK if the build result is small, but when it frequently surpasses 1GB it becomes rather unwieldy and time consuming to copy the build result into an artefact repository, run git commit -a, git push to a remote and then let the docker build environment git pull those changes. I am also worried about how git handles file ownership and permissions.

Comment: It becomes easy now with `RUN --mount`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885945/dockerfile-copy-and-run-in-one-layer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, [the solution IS to use `COPY . /app` as the OP is doing](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21950#issuecomment-208881571), there is however [an open bug causing this not to work as expected on most systems](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21950#issuecomment-208892647)

The only currently feasible workaround to this issue seems to be to use rsync to analyze the differences between the old and new images prior to pushing the new one, then use the changelog output to generate a tar-file containing the relevant changes which is subsequently COPY:ed to a new image layer.

This way, the layer sizes becomes a few bytes or kilobytes for smaller changes instead of 1.2 GB every time.

I put together documentation and scripts to help out with this over at https://github.com/neam/docker-diff-based-layers.

The end results are shown below:

#### Verify that basing the project images on the revision 1 image tag contents does not lead to desired outcome

Verify that subsequent `COPY . /app` commands re-adds all files in every layer instead of only the files that have changed:

```
docker history sample-project:revision-2
```

Output:

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
4a3115eaf267        3 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:61d102421e6692b677   16.78 MB
d4b30af167f4        25 seconds ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:68b8f374d8731b8ad8   16.78 MB
c898fe1daa44        2 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    10.77 MB
39a8a358844a        4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B
b1dacad9c5c9        4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5afd8eec1dc1e7666d   125.1 MB
```

Even though we added/changed only a few bytes, all files are re-added and 16.78 MB is added to the total image size.

Also, the file(s) that we removed did not get removed.

#### Create an image with an optimized layer

```
export RESTRICT_DIFF_TO_PATH=/app
export OLD_IMAGE=sample-project:revision-1
export NEW_IMAGE=sample-project:revision-2
docker-compose -f rsync-image-diff.docker-compose.yml up
docker-compose -f shell.docker-compose.yml -f process-image-diff.docker-compose.yml up
cd output; docker build -t sample-project:revision-2-processed .; cd ..
```

Verify that the processed new image has smaller sized layers with the changes:

```
docker history sample-project:revision-2-processed
```

Output:

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
1920e750d362        24 seconds ago      /bin/sh -c if [ -s /.files-to-remove.list ];    0 B
1267bf926729        2 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5021c627243e841a45   19 B
d04a2181b62a        2 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:14780990c926e673f2   264 B
d4b30af167f4        7 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:68b8f374d8731b8ad8   16.78 MB
c898fe1daa44        9 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    10.77 MB
39a8a358844a        4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B
b1dacad9c5c9        4 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5afd8eec1dc1e7666d   125.1 MB
```

Verify that the processed new image contains the same contents as the original:

```
export RESTRICT_DIFF_TO_PATH=/app
export OLD_IMAGE=sample-project:revision-2
export NEW_IMAGE=sample-project:revision-2-processed
docker-compose -f rsync-image-diff.docker-compose.yml up
```

The output should indicate that there are no differences between the images/tags. Thus, the sample-project:revision-2-processed tag can now be pushed and deployed, leading to the same end result but without having to push an unnecessary 16.78M over the wire, leading to faster deploy cycles.

Comment: It's insane that this bug is not a priority (or even active as far as I can tell).  I'm discovering that docker has very little in the way of practical support for the common pattern of wanting to deploy code and incrementally update it.  Getting a very academia vibe from the whole thing with a lot of "why would you want to do that?" type answers to common real world dev-ops patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Docker caching works per layer / instruction in the Dockerfile. In this case the files used in that layer (everything in the build-context (`.`)) are modified, so the layer needs to be rebuilt.

If there's specific parts of the code that don't change often, you could consider to add those in a separate layer, or even move those to a "base image"

```
FROM mybaseimage
COPY ./directories-that-dont-change-often /somewhere
COPY ./directories-that-change-often /somewhere
```

It may take some planning or restructuring for this to work, depending on your project, but may be worth doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, this both requires planning and restructuring and must thus be seen as a workaround specific to certain projects and not as a general solution. We tried this but could not find a good way to restructure the project's files horizontally based on file modification frequency, neither did we want our developers to be afraid of modifying some directories due to the risk of increased build times.

Answer (score 2):

My solution: (idea from https://github.com/neam/docker-diff-based-layers !)

```
docker rm -f uniquename 2> /dev/null
docker run --name uniquename -v ~/repo/mycode:/src ${REPO}/${IMAGE}:${BASE} rsync -ar --exclude-from '/src/.dockerignore' --delete /src/ /app/
docker commit uniquename ${REPO}/${IMAGE}:${NEW_TAG}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this question is specifically about how to do it without resorting to using docker commit