# Dockerfile COPY and RUN in one layer

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a script used in the preapration of a Docker image. I have this in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY my_script /
RUN bash -c "/my_script"
```

The `my_script` file contains secrets that I don't want in the image (it deletes itself when it finishes).

The problem is that the file remains in the image despite being deleted because the COPY is a separate layer. What I need is for both COPY and RUN to affect the same layer.

How can I COPY and RUN a script so that both actions affect the same layer?

Answer (score 9):

take a look to [multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/):

Use multi-stage builds

> With multi-stage builds, you use multiple FROM statements in your
>   Dockerfile. Each FROM instruction can use a different base, and each
>   of them begins a new stage of the build. You can selectively copy
>   artifacts from one stage to another, **leaving behind everything you
>   don’t want in the final image**. To show how this works, let’s adapt the
>   Dockerfile from the previous section to use multi-stage builds.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Answer (score 7):

As of 18.09 you can use [`docker build --secret`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information) to use secret information during the build process. The secrets are mounted into the build environment and aren't stored in the final image.

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=script,dst=/my_script \
    bash -c /my_script
```

```
$ docker build --secret id=script,src=my_script.sh
```

The script wouldn't need to delete itself.

Comment: So, https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/ this need swarm, but for build this feature is ok without swarm as it seems just for build?

Comment: This would appear to be the solution to my problem, if only it worked! My version (18.09.6-ce, build 481bc77156) does not understand `--mount`.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to exclude file(s) from `COPY`, but use it during the build process (add file to `.dockerignore`, and use secret mount with this file). `docker build` requires `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` environment variable for this to work. Thanks!

Comment: dokcer 19.03.12, still  get ```Unknown flag: mount```. ```DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1``` already set but dot work.

Answer (score 5):

This can be handled by BuildKit:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM ...
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/my_script,source=my_script,rw \
    bash -c "/my_script"
```

You would then build with:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t my_image .
```

---

This also sounds like you are trying to inject secrets into the build, e.g. to pull from a private git repo. BuildKit also allows you to specify:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM ...
RUN --mount=type=secret,target=/creds,id=cred \
    bash -c "/my_script -i /creds"
```

You would then build with:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t my_image --secret id=creds,src=./creds .
```

---

With both of the BuildKit options, the mount command never actually adds the file to your image. It only makes the file available as a bind mount during that single RUN step. As long as that RUN step does not output the secret to another file in your image, the secret is never injected in the image.

For more on the BuildKit experimental syntax, see: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use a workaround to do this:

Put `my_script` in a local http server which for example using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, and then the file could be accessed with `http://http_server_ip:8000/my_script`

Then, in Dockerfile use next:

```
RUN curl http://http_server_ip:8000/my_script > /my_script && chmod +x /my_script && bash -c "/my_script"
```

This workaround assure file add & delete in same layer, of course, you may need to add `curl` install in `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 2):

I think `RUN --mount=type=bind,source=my_script,target=/my_script bash /my_script`  in BuildKit can solve your problem.

First, prepare BuildKit

```sh
export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
docker buildx create --name mybuilder --driver docker-container
docker buildx use mybuilder
```

Then, write your Dockerfile.

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FORM debian
## something

RUN --mount=type=bind,source=my_script,target=/my_script bash -c /my_script
```

The first lint must be **# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental** because it's experimental feature.

And this method are not work in Play with docker, but work on my computer...

My computer us Ubuntu 20.04 with docker 19.03.12

Then, build it with

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t user/imgname -f ./Dockerfile . --push
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Docker (or Podman) with a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage). Note that there are both `ADD --from=` and `COPY --from` [commands available in a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder), as well as the `RUN --mount` command, which can bind-mount files from images built in other stages (as well as files on disk, which is the more typical use).

For the case with a secret, use [`RUN --mount=type=secret`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypesecret).

For the case when avoiding a copy is an image-size optimization, see the example below.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi-minimal:latest as builder

RUN touch /opt/myapp.rpm

FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi-minimal:latest

RUN --mount=target=/builder,from=builder,source=/mnt microdnf install -y /mnt/myapp.rpm
```

The example (fake)builds an RPM in the `builder` stage, and then installs it with `dnf` (without copying it into the output image first).