# Dockerfile: COPY/ADD and RUN with rm in a single layer

Tags: docker

I'd like to execute a `COPY`/`ADD` command and a subsequent `RUN` in a single layer, so that the added file doesn't bloat the final image size. Something in the lines of:

```
WORKDIR /opt/install

# START I want this in a single layer
COPY install.sh /opt/install
RUN ./install.sh && rm install.sh
# END
```

I know I may do it with a `--squash` argument upon build, but I'd like to know if there is any way to do it directly in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dockerfile COPY and RUN in one layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885945/dockerfile-copy-and-run-in-one-layer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use buildkit's `--mount` option to mount your `install.sh` from the build context:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
# ...
WORKDIR /opt/install
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/opt/install/install.sh,source=install.sh ./install.sh
```

For more on buildkit's Dockerfile features, see https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md