# Dockerfile: Copy dependency install files, install them, remove install files to reduce image size

Tags: docker, dockerfile, podman

I'm working on building an image that will serve as a base image for a build and run container for software running in an offline environment.

I have a folder  that has subdirectories <yum_dependencies> and <other_dependencies>

In the <yum_dependencies> sub directory I have .rpms for all the dependencies that were obtained from  `yum --downloadonly` commands, allowing a completely offline install of all the packages.

In the <other_dependencies> folder I have a few install binaries and source .tar.gz that have to be decompressed/moved/built/installed.

Currently my Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM <centos7 base image>
COPY <dependencies> /app/dependencies
RUN yum --disablerepo=* -y localinstall /app/dependencies/yum_dependencies/*.rpm

...
<several binary executions and installations of <other_dependencies>
...

WORKDIR /app
RUN rm -rf /app/dependencies
```

When I run the resulting image, the /app/dependencies folder is gone, but I've noticed that the image size is the same whether I have the last `RUN rm` command or not.

I know technically I could use `--squash` in my build command to reduce it down to one simple layer (and it does work in reducing the size), but that means that absolutely nothing is cached anymore. Is there anyway to preserve the caching layers without them bloating the final image?

Comment: `RUN rm -rf /app/dependencies` can only *increase* the size of your image (because it simply adds a new layer). That `rm -rf` is only useful if you include it at the end of the `RUN yum ...` statement.

Comment: Have you tried using [multistage builds?](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) It copies an artifact from a previous stage into the current stage. For example, you can install a compiler and compile an executable in one stage, then copy the executable into the final image without including a copy of the compiler.

Comment: @larsks Does this mean that the `COPY` statement and `RUN yum` statement are in the same layer? So if I `COPY` the *.rpms and then immediately do `RUN yum ... && rm -rf *.rpm` the copied rpms won't inflate the final image?

Comment: @NickODell I did see that on other questions, unfortunately I'm not doing anything like that. I'm executing a .run install binary and extracting stuff to specific paths.

Comment: What if you tried to COPY the file you're installing into one stage, then use an inter-stage mount to run the file in a new stage without copying it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76670359/530160

Comment: @NickODell That might work actually, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of using `RUN` with `mount` and it will look like

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=<dependencies>,target=/app/dependencies yum --disablerepo=* -y localinstall /app/dependencies/yum_dependencies/*.rpm
```

If you have to call multiple command on files from `/app/dependencies` you have to add `--mount=type=bind,source=<dependencies>,target=/app/dependencies` to each `RUN` command

Or you can merge all those command into one

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=<dependencies>,target=/app/dependencies \
    yum --disablerepo=* -y localinstall /app/dependencies/yum_dependencies/dep1.rpm &&\
    yum --disablerepo=* -y localinstall /app/dependencies/yum_dependencies/dep2.rpm &&\
    yum --disablerepo=* -y localinstall /app/dependencies/yum_dependencies/dep3.rpm &&\
    /app/dependencies/final_installer_script.sh
```

It will generate only one layer and files from `/app/dependencies` won't be a part of the final image, so you don't need to call `rm`

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing thanks to slight alterations from @NickODell suggestion. Thanks!